# Trying to compile zbspac.exe with MinGW Distro

Tags: c

I am using this Git for Zbspac.exe

https://github.com/uyjulian/zbspac

And the following for my MinGW Distro:

https://nuwen.net/mingw.html

I have a MinGW distro set up to target my zbspac.exe Makefile. However, I keep getting bounced for

```
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:25: BitStream.o] Error 2
```

I have BitStream.c and Bitstream.h in the main directory, but it seems the object file doesn't register for the Distro. I feel that it's going to be the same for all the other object files.

My first idea was to create a duplicate file for each .c file into a .o file. This helped clear the issues relating to the .o not being found (although, this solution is probably not ideal). Is there a way to fix this (besides creating duplicate files)?

It then gives me the error

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o zbspac.exe  BitStream.o  ByteArray.o  CmdArgs.o  FileSystem.o  HuffmanDecoder.o  HuffmanEncoder.o  Logger.o  LzssDecoder.o  LzssEncoder.o  MinHeap.o  NexasPacker.o  NexasUnpacker.o  ScriptPacker.o  ScriptUnpacker.o  StringUtils.o  zbspac.o  external/zlib/adler32.o  external/zlib/compress.o  external/zlib/crc32.o  external/zlib/deflate.o  external/zlib/gzclose.o  external/zlib/gzlib.o  external/zlib/gzread.o  external/zlib/gzwrite.o  external/zlib/infback.o  external/zlib/inffast.o  external/zlib/inflate.o  external/zlib/inftrees.o  external/zlib/trees.o  external/zlib/uncompr.o  external/zlib/zutil.o  -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o zbspac.exe BitStream.o ByteArray.o CmdArgs.o FileSystem.o HuffmanDecoder.o HuffmanEncoder.o Logger.o LzssDecoder.o LzssEncoder.o MinHeap.o NexasPacker.o NexasUnpacker.o ScriptPacker.o ScriptUnpacker.o StringUtils.o zbspac.o external/zlib/adler32.o external/zlib/compress.o external/zlib/crc32.o external/zlib/deflate.o external/zlib/gzclose.o external/zlib/gzlib.o external/zlib/gzread.o external/zlib/gzwrite.o external/zlib/infback.o external/zlib/inffast.o external/zlib/inflate.o external/zlib/inftrees.o external/zlib/trees.o external/zlib/uncompr.o external/zlib/zutil.o -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:22: zbspac.exe] Error 2
```

, which is a self-referential error, since I want to be compiling zbspac.exe, not referring to it.

For reference, the Makefile, which has not been edited:

```
EXE_TARGET = zbspac.exe

TXTS = License.txt Readme.txt Instructions.txt PackageFormat.txt ScriptTxtFormat.txt
PROJECT_FILE = Makefile .project .cproject
SRC_DIST = zbspac-src.7z
BIN_DIST = zbspac-bin.7z

CC = i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
LD = i686-w64-mingw32-ld
CFLAGS = -O2 -std=c99 -Werror -Wall -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Iexternal/zlib
LIBS = -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
DIST_MAKE = 7za a

ZLIB_SRCS = external/zlib/adler32.c external/zlib/compress.c external/zlib/crc32.c external/zlib/deflate.c external/zlib/gzclose.c external/zlib/gzlib.c external/zlib/gzread.c external/zlib/gzwrite.c external/zlib/infback.c external/zlib/inffast.c external/zlib/inflate.c external/zlib/inftrees.c external/zlib/trees.c external/zlib/uncompr.c external/zlib/zutil.c
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c) $(ZLIB_SRCS)
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRCS)) 

all: $(EXE_TARGET)

$(EXE_TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(EXE_TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
    
src_dist: $(SRC_DIST)

bin_dist: $(BIN_DIST)

$(SRC_DIST): $(SRCS) $(HEADERS) $(TXTS) $(PROJECT_FILE)
    $(DIST_MAKE) $(SRC_DIST) $(SRCS) $(HEADERS) $(TXTS) $(PROJECT_FILE)

$(BIN_DIST): $(EXE_TARGET) $(TXTS)
    $(DIST_MAKE) $(BIN_DIST) $(EXE_TARGET) $(TXTS)

.PHONY: clean
    
clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(EXE_TARGET) $(SRC_DIST) $(BIN_DIST)
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: I don't think that's the whole error message. Are there some more complaints before the first bit you quoted? If you copied all .c files under .o name (is that what you did?), then the second message is very likely incomplete, it should be preceded by the linker barfing its guts out at all the invalid object files. So let's ignore the second one, is there more detail to the first error message?